# Three.js white screen after loading a lot of objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, chromium

I'm loading a lot (more than 4350) 3D objects from JSON files.

```
    for (var y in game.fields) {
        for (var x in game.fields[y]) {
            switch (game.fields[y][x]) {
                case 'm':
                    Three.loadMountain(x, y)
                    break
                case 'h':
                    Three.loadHill(x, y)
                    break
            }
        }
    }
```

I can see objects appearing on screen but at certain moment everything goes white. What can it be? Can I debug it somehow? There is no message in console and I'm using Chromium browser.

Methods:

```
this.loadMountain = function (x, y) {
    loader.load('/models/mountain.json', getGeomHandler('#808080', x * 4 - 216, y * 4 - 311, 1));
}
this.loadHill = function (x, y) {
    loader.load('/models/hill.json', getGeomHandler('#008000', x * 4 - 216, y * 4 - 311, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Don't use loader.load in loop. Instead add meshes to scene inside callback function.

EXAMPLE:

```
loader.load('/models/mountain.json', function(geometry){
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#808080'})
    for (var y in game.fields) {
        for (var x in game.fields[y]) {
            switch (game.fields[y][x]) {
                case 'm':
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    mesh.position.set(x, 0, y);
                    scene.add(mesh);
                 break
            }
        }
    }
});
```